# Изменения стиля приложения при смене вкладов TabHost

Tags: android-sdk, android-fragment, android, activity

Доброго дня! Есть Activity унаследованный от FragmentActivity в котором создается TabHost с 3 вкладками (Две из которых ListFragment а третья вкладка простой Fragment). Так вот в 3 вкладке унаследованной от Fragment при переходе на нее нужно изменить teme приложения. Погуглив нашел такую вещь что нужно пересоздать activity для того чтобы тема применилась.    Метода recreate используется только с API 11, а мне нужно чтобы поддержка начиналась API 8 Android 2.2.

**EDIT:** Отредактировал тему и содержания вопроса, в связи с изучением и понимаем проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

В фрагменте добавить:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(null);
        actionBar.setSubtitle(null);
    }
```

В onCreate добавить

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Comment: Я не использую ActionBar. Соответственно он не понимает что такое ActionBarActivity. Либо я что то не понимаю. И разве ActionBar саппортиться не начиная с 11 версии*?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html В support v7 есть поддержка ActionBar. 

Если вы не используете ActionBar, то о каком заголовке речь? Выложите картинку например.

Comment: Добавил screen. Не судите строго не так давно в этом во всем разбираюсь.

Comment: Мы строго и не судим :) Наверное для всех табов нужно установить Listeners tab.setTabListener и в каждом проверять, если это нужный вам таб, то скрывать заголовок setVisible(View.GONE), а если это не нужный таб, то показывать if(getVisible() == View.GONE) setVisible(View.Visible)

Comment: @Bjick Но все же вы наверное хотели бы пользоваться ActionBar. Так что используйте support-library

Comment: У меня есть OnTabChangeListener, но как добраться непосредственно до самого моего кастомного Title? Ума не приложу!) getTitle возвращает последовательность символов заголовка.

Comment: @Bjick Значит я совсем не понимаю что вам надо сделать. Title и есть заголовок.

Comment: @Deadkenny Может теперь вы меня поймете и поможете решить проблему!)